# Why do i get this value in logical operator and java?

Tags: java

I have a question with the value of variable x.
I hope the following output

> false and Valor de x = 1

but

> false and Valor de x = 0

why?

thnks

```
class Numero{

    public static void main(String... args){
        int x = 0;

        if((x>1) && (x++ >=0) & (x++>=1))
            System.out.println("true and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
        else
            System.out.println("false and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude , time to change your translator. :(

Comment: Code like this `if` statement is impossible to follow.  Mixing `&&` and `&` in the same expression, without parentheses, is a very bad idea, since it means I have to go back to the language reference to figure out which one has precedence.  Using `x` and `x++` together in the same expression (and especially using `x++` more than once) is also a bad idea because we have to worry about which order things are evaluated in.  In Java this is well-defined; in other languages this could produce different results on different compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `&&` operator, you stop evaluating the conditions on the first failing condition. So in your case you stop reading the other conditions after having `x>1` = false. If you want all the conditions to be evaluated no matter if it fails at a certain condition, use a single `&` operator

```
public static void main(String... args){
    int x = 0;

    if((x>1) & (x++ >=0) & (x++>=1))
        System.out.println("true and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
    else
        System.out.println("false and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
}
```

Comment: ok it´s short-circuit but I use the & operator in the expression should be evaluated?

Comment: *because* of short-circuiting that expression will not be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args){
    int x = 0;        // x is 0;

    if((x>1) && (x++ >=0) & (x++>=1)) // x=0. SO, x>1 fails, if is not executed, else is executed. 
        System.out.println("true and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
    else
        System.out.println("false and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because this is an AND operation. Once the first test fails, the `if` statement stops checking. It wouldn't make sense for the other operations to complete if there's no chance of the statement being any value other than `false` (or `true` if you had another case, such as `x<1`). Thus, `x` is never incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The initial condition checks whether x>1 or not. Since initially, x=0, this condition fails, and as a result, the else part is executed. In this part, the value of x is still 0 (since no change has occurred in the value of x).

Note that, in an '&&' scenario, if the first condition fails, then the second condition is not evaluated at all. The second condition gets evaluated only if the first condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you change && to & then it will execute all condition.

- hence (x>1) false condition.
- (x++>=0) here x=0 and increment next      time true condition.
- (x++>=1) here x=1 and increment next time true    condition.

There are two true condition one false gives false.

so the output will be----false and Valor de x = 2

```
class Numero{

        public static void main(String... args){
        int x = 0;

        if((x>1) & (x++ >=0) & (x++>=1))      //&& to &
            System.out.println("true and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
        else
            System.out.println("false and " + "Valor de x = " + x);
    }
}
```

& is bitwise. && is logical.
& evaluates both sides of the operation.
&& evaluates the left side of the operation, if it's true, it continues and evaluates the right side.